Google Play Console automated check rejects app submission for USE_EXACT_ALARM but it's not present
In the Google Play Console, the following issue related to USE_EXACT_ALARM is blocking a new version submission:

The declaration is not relevant because this is not an alarm clock or calendar app.
However, USE_EXACT_ALARM is not present in the app:

The previous version of the app did include USE_EXACT_ALARM, but it is now removed in the new bundle we are trying to submit.
Creating a new versionName, new versionCode, and cleaning/rebuilding before generating a new app bundle did not resolve the issue.
Any ideas of how to get out of automated check purgatory?

Check also bundles / APKs in test tracks if used and update them accordingly.

Thanks, that has done the trick. After updating a test version not to include USE_EXACT_ALARM first and then updating the Production version, it's not getting flagged anymore. Thanks!!!
